# Yii2 bootstrap dropdown issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, widget, yii2, dropdown

I am trying to put a yii dropdown widget into my application. I do this the way it's shown here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-bootstrap-dropdown.html.

```
use yii/bootstrap/Dropdown;
...

<ul>
...
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Label <b class="caret"></b></a>                     
    <?php
        echo Dropdown::widget([
            'items'  => [
                 ['label' => 'DropdownA', 'url' => '#'],
                 ['label' => 'DropdownB', 'url' => '#'],
              ],
        ]);
    ?>
</li> 
...
</ul>
```

**But the link does not expand.** Please, show me what i am doing wrong.

And these are the AppAssets:

```
public $css = [
    //'css/site.css',S
    'newtemp/styles/style.css',
    'newtemp/styles/animate.css',
    'newtemp/styles/font-awesome.css',
    'newtemp/styles/font-awesome2.css',
    'newtemp/styles/framework.css',
    'newtemp/styles/owl.theme.css',
    'newtemp/styles/swipebox.css',
    'newtemp/styles/bootstrap.css',


];
public $js = [

    'newtemp/scripts/jqueryui.js',
    'newtemp/scripts/contact.js',
    'newtemp/scripts/framework.js',
    'newtemp/scripts/framework.launcher.js',
    'newtemp/scripts/framework.plugins.js',
    'newtemp/scripts/custom.js',
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: what exactly not working?

Comment: @IncognitoSkulll Class 'yii\bootstap\Dropdown' not found

Comment: reverse your slashes `use yii\bootstap\Dropdown`

Comment: @IncognitoSkulll no, it does not work this way. syntax error, unexpected '/', expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: put `;` also `use yii\bootstap\Dropdown;`

Comment: @IncognitoSkulll i had a typo, thanks. but the button does not expand.

Comment: it's working.. i have tested your code.